# Eigen Values/Vectors of large scale data

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Recently I have tried to learn the concepts of Eigen Values and Vectors and I have currently managed to calculate the Eigen values and vectors based off a 2x2 matrix  based off calculating the covariance matrix etc..

My problem is, I'm currently trying to perform analysis of a spectrogram, and, the dimensions for this data is `451x128` but I've only ever seen material related to calculating the eigen values and vectors based on `2x2` and `3x3`.

Is it possible to be able to calculate such based on such high dimensional data?

The spectrogram data looks something as follows:

```
0.0009    0.0057    0.0049    0.0014    0.0053    0.0017    0.0026    0.0017
0.0035    0.0001    0.0009    0.0022    0.0002    0.0008    0.0019    0.0022
0.0026    0.0008    0.0001    0.0031    0.0052    0.0071    0.0055    0.0028
0.0024    0.0019    0.0080    0.0040    0.0006    0.0001    0.0001    0.0021
0.0133    0.0071    0.0033    0.0006    0.0002    0.0004    0.0011    0.0018
```

When I calculate the covariance matrix, assuming the `2x2` principle then I get the following:

```
Eigen Values: 22.58347e-06 1.09907e-07 
Eigen Vectors: 0.941228 -0.337771
```

Whereas matlab gives me a completely different dimensionality when computing the eigen values and vectors.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing. Your data matrix is non-square. Are you trying to perform a Principle Component Analysis (PCA) of the data? If not, perhaps you should. In such a case, you will be computing the eigenvectors of the symmetric matrix $XX^T$.

Comment: It's totally possible to compute eigenvalues for high dimensional data.  Your problem isn't the dimension, it's that you're using a 451x128 array.  You need to have the same number of columns as rows to compute eigenvalues.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Hey, thanks for the reply. Assume that in C++ I have the following: `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` this gives a $2 X 2$ matrix of `541x128` array. Then I compute the covariance matrix of size `128x128` now my question is this: Can I still use the equation: $$\frac{a+b\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c^2)}}2.$$ ? Computing this only the produces a `2 x 2` matrix giving the Eigen values and another giving the Eigen values.. It's still 2x2 this is therefore correct?

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are defined for squared matrix only. In the case of non-squared matrix we talk about singular values and singular vectors. Algorithm for computing singular vectors and values exists and are well-studied. See [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD on matlab).